# Problema con POST y AJAX

Tags: php, mysqli

El problema es que envío un formulario con AJAX en POST. Todo va bien en el PRIMER ENVIO, ahora si hago el segundo envío, se guarda el doble de si mismo, y al tercer envio, el triple de si mismo, y así sucesivamente. Entonces, podrían indicarme alguna forma de limpiar el POST o lo que sea que haya que limpiar para evitar este problema?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Cuando hay más de una inserción, multiplica....
La verdad que estoy realmente confundido.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo del archivo "polling.js" que activa la carga de la pagina "test.php" en donde se muestran cada una de las inserciones desde MySQL.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
 $('#message').load('test.php');
 setInterval(function() {
  $('#message').load('test.php');
 }, 1000);
});
```

Codigo de la pagina principal - "test-inside.php"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
 <title></title>
 <script src="js/jq-1.11.3.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bst.min.js"></script>
 <script src="post-form.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bst.min.css">
</head>
<body style="background:none;font-family:Trebuchet MS;">
<div class="container">
 <div style="width:100%;height:300px;">
  <h1 style="margin:0;padding:0;width:100%;text-align:center;">NuevaRed Development Testing</h1>
  <form method="POST" id="form">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" style="border-radius:15px;" id="texto" name="texto" placeholder="Escribe tu mensaje" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
     <button type="submit" onclick="quebueno();" class="form-control btn btn-primary" style="border-radius:15px;" name="send">Enviar</button>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
  <div id="message" style="height:350px;overflow-y:scroll;padding:5px;margin:0;"></div>
 </div>
 
</div>
<script src="polling.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Codigo de inserción a MySQL - "sendmessage.php" la pagina que hace el proceso de guardar en MySQL y luego es mostrada en "test.php"

```html
<?php
require 'conec.php';
if($link){
 if(!empty($_POST['texto'])){
  require 'class.php';
  $inputText = $_POST['texto'];
     $inputKey = "MaximaPuertaServiceReina17Milena";
     $blockSize = 256;
     $aes = new AES($inputText, $inputKey, $blockSize);
     if($enc = $aes->encrypt()){
      $sql=mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO testing(e,Location) VALUES ('$enc','Here')");
     }else{
      echo "Nope!";
     }
 }else{
  echo "Escribe algo antes de enviar, plox.";
 }
}
?>
```

Codigo "test.php" donde se muestra la data almacenada en MySQL.

```html
<?php
require 'conec.php';
require 'class.php';
$inputKey = "MaximaPuertaServiceReina17Milena";
$blockSize = 256;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="mensajes">
<?php
if($sql=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM testing ORDER BY id_test DESC")){
 if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0){
  while ($filas = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
   $us = $filas['e'];
   $inputText = $us;
      $aes = new AES($inputText, $inputKey, $blockSize);
      if($enc = $aes->decrypt()){
       if($filas['Location']=="Here"){
       ?>
        <div class="s-pred" style="text-align:left;position:relative;width:75%;padding:5px 10px;">
         <table>
          <tr>
           <td>
            <h2 style="font-size:16px;text-align:left;margin:0;padding:0;"><?php echo $enc ?></h2>
           </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>
            <h2 style="margin:0;padding:0;font-size:12px;text-align:left;"><b><?php echo $filas['Location'] ?></b></h2>
           </td>
          </tr>
         </table>
        </div>
       <?php
       }elseif($filas['Location']=="There"){
       ?>
        <div class="s-pred" style="text-align:right;width:75%;position:relative;left:25%;padding:5px 10px;">
         <table>
          <tr>
           <td>
            <h2 style="font-size:16px;text-align:right;margin:0;padding:0;"><?php echo $enc ?></h2>
           </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>
            <h2 style="margin:0;padding:0;font-size:12px;text-align:right;"><b><?php echo $filas['Location'] ?></b></h2>
           </td>
          </tr>
         </table>
        </div>
       <?php
       }
      }
  }
 }else{
  ?>
  <h4 style="width:100%;text-align:center;">No hay mensajes, ¿Dónde está la amistad? :v</h4>
  <?php
 }
}else{
 echo "HEY!!";
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Código de "post-form.js" el cual es responsable de hacer el registro a MySQL.

```js
function quebueno(){
    $('#form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()//evitas hacer el submit
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'sendmessage.php',
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("Sended!");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Bueno tengo rato que no toco PHP ni nada de eso, pero tienes alguna excepcion para evitar guardar el mismo en la base de datos, por que si guardas el mismo texto pero con una llave primeria diferente lo hara

Comment: Cómo sería eso? @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales

Comment: A mi me parece que si se guardan bien, para asegurarte podrias hacer la consulta directamente a la base de datos. Aver si te salen triplicados. Pero no creo que sea el caso. Quizas el problema esta donde imprimes lo que obtienes. Intenta hacer la consulta directamente en base de datos y a ver que devuelve. Esta "SELECT * FROM testing ORDER BY id_test DESC"

Comment: @GabrielEduardoToledo lo que creo es que esta haciendo la consulta pero no limpia la vista, entonces cuando llama una consulta la muestra sobre otra si es eso pues

Comment: Extrañamente si resultan multiplicados en la base de datos también. @GabrielEduardoToledo

Comment: Y @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales, explicame por favor.

Comment: Cuando lo envío sin AJAX, envia normalmente, sin multiplicar las inserciones en base de datos, pero debe haber una forma de limpiar el POST luego de enviar, ya que AJAX no actualiza la página y eso es bueno. Pero la información nunca se borra y por lo tanto multiplica las inserciones. Y esa es la razón por la que el primer envío no tiene ese problema y los demás sí.

Comment: Pero no sé cómo "limpiar" el POST.

Comment: @MattewJaneey no se trata de limpiar el POST, si no en donde estas cargando la informacion, cada que recibas el JSON de una nueva consulta debes limpiar el div o donde sea que muestres eso, si usas jquery busca algo que se llama empty()

Comment: Y cómo se supone que debo usar "empty()"? @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales

Answer (score 3):

El problema está en el JavaScript y es bastante interesante (o al menos a mí me lo parece). Éste es el código de la función `quebueno`:

```
function quebueno(){
    $('#form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()//evitas hacer el submit
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'sendmessage.php',
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("Sended!");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Cada vez que se ejecuta `quebueno` se asociado un controlador del evento `submit` al formulario con id `form`. Ahora vamos a ver cómo se llama a `quebueno`:

```
<form method="POST" id="form">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" style="border-radius:15px;" id="texto" name="texto" placeholder="Escribe tu mensaje" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
                <button type="submit" onclick="quebueno();" class="form-control btn btn-primary" style="border-radius:15px;" name="send">Enviar</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Se llama cuando se pulsa en el botón que envía el formulario. ¿Qué significa esto? Que cada vez que se pulsa el botón se está asociando el controlador del submit al formulario, y el controlador realiza la llamada AJAX. Por tanto con cada pulso del botón se añade un nuevo controlador y una nueva llamada. Por eso el primer dato se guarda una vez, el segundo dos veces, el tercero tres veces...

Por ejemplo, estos serían los pasos que sigue el código actual:

1. El usuario pulsa en el botón que llama a quebueno
2. quebueno asocia el controlador (que llamaré controlador 1) al evento submit del formulario
3. Se llama al evento submit del formulario y el dato se guardará una vez

   1. El controlador 1 corre y se hace una llamada AJAX que guarda el valor.
4. El usuario pulsa en el botón que llama a quebueno
5. quebueno asocia el controlador (que llamaré controlador 2) al evento submit del formulario
6. Se llama al evento submit del formulario (y el dato se guardará 2 veces)

   1. El controlador 1 corre y se hace una llamada AJAX que guarda el valor.
   2. El controlador 2 corre y se hace una llamada AJAX que guarda el valor.
7. El usuario pulsa en el botón que llama a quebueno
8. quebueno asocia el controlador (que llamaré controlador 3) al evento submit del formulario
9. Se llama al evento submit del formulario (y el dato se guardará 3 veces)

   1. El controlador 1 corre y se hace una llamada AJAX que guarda el valor.
   2. El controlador 2 corre y se hace una llamada AJAX que guarda el valor.
   3. El controlador 3 corre y se hace una llamada AJAX que guarda el valor.
10. ...

La solución es sencilla:

1. Quita la llamada a `quebueno` del botón que envía el formulario

   ```
   <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary" style="border-radius:15px;" name="send">Enviar</button>
   ```
2. Mueve el contenido de `quebueno` para que se ejecute cuando se cargue la página:

   ```
   $("document").ready(function() {
       $('#form').submit(function(e) {
           e.preventDefault()//evitas hacer el submit
           $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: 'sendmessage.php',
               data: $('#form').serialize(),
               success: function(data) {
                   console.log("Sended!");
               }
           });
       });
   });
   ```

Como ahora sólo se asocia un único controlador (cuando se carga la página), los datos sólo se guardarán una vez y no de manera repetida.

Comment: Triple rayos... Definitivamente sin palabras. Lo intentaré.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz Perfecto. Dime qué tal te fue :)

Comment: Funcionó perfecto.

Answer (score 1):

Debes pegarle un repaso a javascript ir por partes, para que no te pierdas facil, de igual manera, seria algo asi:

### html

```
<div id="lista_mensajes"></div>
```

### js

```
var lista;
lista = $('#lista_mensajes');
lista.empty();
lista.append(objeto, string, etc);
```

En el js estoy usando jquery, no se si lo usas

Comment: Pero estoy paralelo con MySQL, cada post es una inserción

Comment: @MáximaAlekz puedes poner el objeto que te retorna?

Comment: No he entendido

Comment: @MáximaAlekz s supone que deseas poner una información que te llega luego de una consulta, bueno esa información viene en un JSON, podrías mostrar que esta retornando

Comment: No uso JSON. Disculpa...

Comment: Entonces que formato utilizas para retornar los valores??