# Error en ejecucion de funcion en un objeto

Tags: javascript

Lo que quiero lograr es que ***si el mensaje tiene igual o mas de 15 caracteres me mostraria*** `this.c` como `true` osino como `false`, ***pero me muestra*** `undefined`.. por que?

```js
function A() {
  
  this.mp = function(msg) {
    
    this.c = msg.length >= 15 ? true : false;
    
    return this.c;
    
  };
  
 var to = (function() {
   
   window.addEventListener("load", function(){
     
     document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("click", function(){
       
       this.mp(document.getElementById("a").value.toString());
       console.log(this.c);
  
     });
     
   });
   
   
 }).bind(this)();
  
  
}

document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("click", function(){
  
  nw = new A();
  
  console.log(this.mp);
  
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="a" placeholder="Mensaje"/>
<input type="button" id="b" value="Enviar mensaje"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que `this` no es lo que crees que es aquí:

```
document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("click", function(){
  nw = new A();
  console.log(this.mp);
});
```

estás asociando un controlador del evento `click` al botón b. Y dentro de ese controlador, creas un nuevo `A()` y se lo asignas a `nw`. Luego haces `this.mp`... Pero `this` en ese contexto es el botón b, que no contiene ningún método `mp`; por eso recibes `undefined`. Es `nw` el que contiene el método, por lo que deberías hacer `nw.mp()`. Pero aún hay más. `mp` toma un parámetro con la cadena y no le estarías pasando nada. Tienes que pasarle la cadena con el valor del campo de texto a.

Cambiando esas dos cosas, ya funcionaría:

```
document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("click", function() {
  nw = new A();
  console.log(nw.mp(document.getElementById("a").value));
});
```

Como puedes ver en esta demo:

```js
function A() {

  this.mp = function(msg) {
    this.c = msg.length >= 15 ? true : false;
    return this.c;
  };

  var to = (function() {
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.mp(document.getElementById("a").value.toString());
        console.log(this.c);
      });
    });
  }).bind(this)();

}

document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("click", function() {
  nw = new A();
  console.log(nw.mp(document.getElementById("a").value));
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="a" placeholder="Mensaje" />
  <input type="button" id="b" value="Enviar mensaje" />
</body>

</html>
```

---

En los comentarios, dices que por qué no funciona incluso cuando está puesto de manera similar en la función interna `to`. Voy a explicar en esta edición por qué ése es el caso y por qué es el comportamiento esperado (y también por qué no debería hacerse de ese modo).

Vamos a analizar el código:

```
var to = (function() {
   window.addEventListener("load", function(){
     document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("click", function(){ 
       this.mp(document.getElementById("a").value.toString());
       console.log(this.c);
     });
   });
 }).bind(this)();
```

Creas una función (que llamas automáticamente intentando cambiar el `this` con `bind`) que añade un controlador del evento `load` de la ventana en el que se pondrá un controlador del evento `click` al botón... y aquí está el primer problema.

La ventana ya se ha cargado antes de llamar a `to` (porque se llama cuando ya se haya pulsado en el botón, ver problema con esto más adelante). Entonces añadir un controlador del evento `load` al `window` no produce ningún resultado porque ese evento ya se disparó y no se va a volver a disparar. Vamos a eliminarlo:

```
var to = (function() {
   document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("click", function(){ 
     this.mp(document.getElementById("a").value.toString());
     console.log(this.c);
   });
 }).bind(this)();
```

Perfecto. Ahora con este código ya se dispara el controlador del `click`... aunque hay que pulsar una segunda vez para que se dispare el controlador que se acaba de asociar pero recibimos un error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.mp is not a function at HTMLInputElement.

¿Por qué ocurre eso? Por lo mismo que comentaba al principio de esta respuesta: `this` no es lo que crees que es. Aunque hayas cambiado el valor de `this` con `bind`, ahora estás dentro de la función del controlador del evento `click` y el `this` ha cambiado para ser el botón. Esto se podría solucionar cambiando el valor del `this` en el controlador llamando de nuevo a `bind`:

```
var to = (function() {
   document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("click", (function(){ 
     this.mp(document.getElementById("a").value.toString());
     console.log(this.c);
   }).bind(this));
 }).bind(this)();
```

¡Perfecto! Ya funciona... ¿o no? Ahora sí que por fin devuelve el valor correcto, pero hay un problema adicional - cada vez que pulso el botón se muestra el resultado una vez más: la primera vez se muestra una vez, la segunda vez se muestra dos veces, la tercera vez se muestra tres veces... y así.

¿Por qué ocurre eso? Ahora hay que mirar a otro culpable:

```
document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("click", function(){
  nw = new A();
  //console.log(this.mp);
});
```

Cada vez que se pulsa el botón, se llama a la función del controlador, se crea un `A()`, que llama a su `to`, que asocia un nuevo controlador al botón... así que cada vez que se pulsa el botón, se está asociando un nuevo controlador. Por eso ahora el resultado se muestra múltiples veces.

¿Cómo podría solucionar eso? Bueno, hay diferentes modos. Pero quizás lo mejor sería que no se asociase un controlador del evento `click` para el botón dentro de `to`. Así matarías dos pájaros de un tiro: no se repetirán las acciones múltiples veces y no hará falta pulsar dos veces el botón para ver el resultado.

Entonces el código de `to` quedaría así:

```
var to = (function() {
   this.mp(document.getElementById("a").value.toString());
   console.log(this.c);
 }).bind(this)();
```

Y el código final quedaría así:

```js
function A() {

  this.mp = function(msg) {
    this.c = msg.length >= 15 ? true : false;
    return this.c;
  };

  var to = (function() {
    this.mp(document.getElementById("a").value.toString());
    console.log(this.c);
  }).bind(this)();
  
}

document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("click", function() {
  nw = new A();
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="a" placeholder="Mensaje" />
<input type="button" id="b" value="Enviar mensaje" />
```

Comment: Pero yo ya le pasaba el campo del valor a la funcion mp, se lo enviaba desde var to = function

Comment: @EduardoSebastian Eso es la función `to`, ¿dónde se llama en el código?

Comment: this.mp(document.getElementById("a").value.toString());

Comment: de hecho, si elimino la linea que yo tenia en la que le paso el valor, sigue funcionando? que?!!

Comment: @EduardoSebastian ¿Qué línea estás eliminando? No me termina de quedar claro lo que dices. ¿Tu código funciona si eliminas qué línea?

Comment: dentro de la expresion funcion to, donde llamo a la funcion this.mp() y le paso el valor del campo del input

Comment: @EduardoSebastian He actualizado la respuesta para explicar por qué no funciona esa parte y cómo podrías arreglarlo. Dime si no se entiende algo y lo edite de nuevo.

Comment: gracias, pero como eso de que 'asociar un nuevo controlador al boton, multiplica  el resultado? , por que?

Comment: @EduardoSebastian porque se ejecuta `nw = A()` con cada click en el botón. Entonces se crea un nuevo `A()` cada vez, que llama a su método `to` por defecto, que asocia un nuevo controlador de evento click al botón (con `document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("click", function() { ... }`)... y los controladores de eventos se van acumulando porque con `addEventListener` se pueden incluir más de uno. Así con cada click se sumaba uno más

Comment: ah, gracias alvaro . me podrias dar documentacion de eso de la acumulacion de eventos, por favor?

Comment: @EduardoSebastian No sé si habrá documentación oficial sobre eso. Alguien hizo una pregunta con un problema parecido, le expliqué paso a paso por qué ocurría eso, y (creo) se veía claramente entonces dónde estaba el problema. Encontré estás dos respuestas, espero que te sirvan: [1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/17981/250) y [2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/20429/250)