# Error al insertar datos en tabla, registro duplicado

Tags: php, ajax

saludos. Soy nueva por aquí, mi problema es el siguiente. Mi script esta realizando una inserción duplicada a la bd después de ejecutarse por primera vez.

Ejemplo: Primera inserción: bien, inserta 1 sola vez el registro.

Segunda inserción (esta se realiza luego de hacer un .load() de ajax a la sección en la que muestro los datos): inserta dos veces el mismo registro.

Tercera inserción: inserta 3 veces el mismo registro, y así sucesivamente.

La funcionalidad es que luego de insertar el comentario, hacer un .load() a la sección de los comentarios para ver el nuevo comentario, y si se quiere volver a insertar otro pues me permita hacerlo, y aquí esta el problema, después del primer insert, realiza los demás insert duplicados.

Estas son mis funciones:

AJAX:

```
jQuery(document).on('submit','#comment_form',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if($("#comment").val()=="" || $("#n").val()==""){
        $("#alert").html('Fill the fields');
    }else if($("#comment").val().length > 300){
        $("#alert").html('We allow 300 characters maximum for a comment');
    }else if(!expr.test($("#n").val())){
        $("#alert").html('Write a correct name');
    } else {
        jQuery.ajax({
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            url:'core/bin/goComent.php',
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("#submit").attr("disabled","disabled");
                $("#submit").val("Sending");
            }
        })

        .done(function(json){
            console.log(json);
            if(json.success == true){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#commentss").load("core/viewsComments.php").fadeIn('slow');
                },1000);
                $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("#submit").val("Post Comment");
                $("#n").val("");
                $("#comment").val("");
                return false;
            } else {
                $("#alert").html(json);
            }
        })
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
  if($_POST){
  $jsondata = array();
  $comment = strip_tags($_POST['comment']);
  $name = strip_tags($_POST['n']);
  $url = $_POST['url'];
   if(empty($url)){
     $url = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
   }
   if(!empty($name) or !empty($comment)){
     require('../clases/classConexion.php');
     include '../libs/geoIP/geoiploc.php';
     $db = new Conexion();
     $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
     //$pais = getCountryFromIP($ip,'name');
     $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO comentarios(nombre,comentario,ip,url,date_)VALUES(?,?,?,?,NOW())");
    if($sql->execute(array($name,$comment,$ip,$url))){
        $jsondata['success'] = true;
    } else {
        $jsondata['success'] = false;
        $jsondata['msj'] = $sql->errorInfo()[2];
    }
   } else {
    echo '<script>alert("Empty Data, NO");</script>';
   }
   } else {
     echo '<script>alert("You can not enter here");</script>';
   }
   header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
   echo json_encode($jsondata);
   exit();
?>
```

No he conseguido el porque de este problema! Reviso y reviso y no doy con el error.

Comment: He conseguido respuesta a mi pregunta aqui: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/15091/problema-con-post-y-ajax